# Where I should placed the "coap+tcp" uri?

Tags: iot, coap, californium

I'm trying to write `CoAP` client protocol implementation for embedded device.
Now I'm working on tcp-implementation.

I don't understand where I should placed "coap+tcp" uri in the request.
I'm testing my code with `Californium`, so that works fine without that uri.

But in the sources of `Californium` i saw options:

- *"coap"*
- *"coaps"*
- *"coap+tcp"*
- *"coaps+tcp"*

I dont't understand purpose of that. 
May anybody explain how to work with that in client-context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand it, URI Scheme is mainly (if consider only technical side) intended for clients to apply the default port if it is not defined:

[RFC7252 Section 6.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7252#section-6.2)

> All of the requirements listed above for the "coap" scheme are also
> requirements for the "coaps" scheme, except that a default UDP port
> of 5684 is assumed if the port subcomponent is empty or not given,
> and the UDP datagrams MUST be secured through the use of DTLS as
> described in Section 9.1.

I've found no any direct mentions in the RFC that the PDU should contain the scheme.